# recursive function with double output

Tags: java, recursion

I am trying to make an recursive function. i will be an integer, however the output will be an double. I know the function cannot take an double to start, however when the function reaches it maximum "depth", i will still be an integer. When it will go "up" the output will become an double, but i do not understand why the function will not work.

```
long sum1(int i) {
  if(i==1) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return sum1(i-1) + 1/i;
  }
}
```

This is my code to perform this serie:

1. series1(i) = 1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + . . . 1/i

The output does not give an error, but the result is not compute correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all `1/i` will always be 0 when `i` > 1, since you are dividing two `int`s.

Second of all, since the return type is `long`, any fractions will be truncated anyway.

You should return a `double` for an accurate result:

```
double sum1(int i) {
  if(i==1) {
    return 1.0;
  } else {
    return sum1(i-1) + 1.0/i;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works now. If i understand it correctly long is a type of an integer? My teacher said that long was needed to make recursive function.

Comment: @T.v.L. `long` is an integer type whose size is 8 bytes. This allows it to hold larger (and smaller negative) values compared to `int` (which only has 4 bytes). The return type of a recursive function depends on what you need to return. `long` is not necessarily needed.

Comment: That explains a lot. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well the problem for the wrong calculation is that `sum1(i-1) + 1/i;` results in an integer calculation. And 1/i when i is integer >1 is always = 0.

Just use double for the recursion and you can pass int argument.

```
double sum1(double i) {
          if(i==1) {
            return 1;
          } else {
            return sum1(i-1) + 1/i;
          }
        }
```